# How do I make the button have rounded corners while still doing the animation?

Tags: javascript, button

I got this code from code pen but I am looking make sure the button ALWAYS has rounded corners. I do not want sharp corners. I need to have rounded corners both before and on hover.

How can I do this? I am not sure how i can change it because when i added rounded corners then for some reason it left a weird outline still.

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
      background: black;
    }
    
    a {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: Helvetica;
    }
    
    a,
    span {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    svg {
      width: 230px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    /* THE ROUND PSEUDO-ELEMENT HOVER STYLES */
    
    .round,
    .svg,
    .highlight {
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /* THE SVG HOVER EFFECTS */
    
    .svg .button {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 230px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .svg .button:nth-child(3) {
      overflow: visible;
      position: relative;
      top: -20px;
    }
    
    .svg .button rect {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      stroke-width: 4px;
      stroke-dashoffset: 400px;
      stroke: olivedrab;
    }
    
    .svg .button span {
      color: olivedrab;
      width: 230px;
      height: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      line-height: 40px;
      transition: all .2s linear;
      border-radius: 50px;
    }
    
    .svg .button span:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background: olivedrab;
      transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1.25s 0, 1.15, 1, 1);
      transition-delay: .5s;
    }
    
    .svg .button:nth-child(1):hover rect {
      animation: draw1 .75s linear forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes draw1 {
      0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 300;
        stroke-dashoffset: 700;
        stroke-width: 4px;
      }
      75% {
        stroke-dasharray: 900;
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 900;
        stroke-width: 1px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="svg">
    <a class="button" href="#">
      <svg>
        <rect height="40" width="230" fill="transparent" />
      </svg>
      <span>Button1</span>
    </a>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `border-radius` ?

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work properly if you tried it

Comment: yeah, I didn't try it because you haven't made it into a running snippet, so ... too much work to do that'

Comment: oh, it's the SVG that has the sharp corners ... the span doesn't even have a border, so a border-radius on that is irrelevant

Comment: you need "ry" and "rx" attributes on the `<rect>`

Comment: what do u mean ry and rx?

Comment: I mean the `ry` and `rx` attributes that instruct a `<rect>` to have rounded corners - read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect)

Answer (score 0):

```
<rect height="40" width="230" rx="20" ry="20" fill="transparent" />
```

Comment: Check out this jsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ratpack309/d3w3zs89/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=d3w3zs89)

Comment: I see a square button - but then, I use Firefux, not Chrum

Comment: Updated. Sorry. I didn't realize that was a part of the element and not css.